# What model should I use to get the best three predictions for one observation?

Tags: machine-learning, model-selection

Sorry, I'm a noobie, the problem is: I have a dataset with cars available for sale in different locations, so I have attributes like year built, miles, brand, model, # of doors, # of seats, style, etc.., and longitude and latitude of the seller. I want to compare a couple of models that will predict the best three choices located closer to a specific observation and preferably that has been built recently.
I was thinking of a KNN model with k = 3, and for the other model I would like to use a random forest or gradient boost but I believe they will give me just one prediction right?